# how to replace or remove all text strings outside of parenthesis in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am very new to Regex and I am trying to remove all text outside the parenthesis and only keep everything inside the parenthesis.

For example 1,

```
Hello,this_isLuxy.(example)
```

to this:

```
(example)
```

Example 2:remove everything after the period

```
luxySO_i.example
```

to this:

```
luxySO_i
```

Using JS + Regex? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

For this simple string, you can use `indexOf` and `substring` functions:

```
var openParenthesisIndex = str.indexOf('(');
var closedParenthesisIndex = str.indexOf(')', openParenthesisIndex);
var result = str.substring(openParenthesisIndex, closedParenthesisIndex + 1);
```

Ok, if you want to use regex, then it's going to be a bit complicated. Anyways, here you go:

```
var str = "Hello,this_(isL)uxy.(example) asd (todo)";
var result = str.replace(/[^()](?=([^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*$)/g, '');
console.log(result); // "(isL)(example)(todo)"
```

In short, this replaces any non `()` character, which is followed by zero or more balanced parenthesis. It will fail for nested or non-balanced parenthesis though.

Comment: Thanks so much Rohit. I would like to use regex for consistency purposes. It would be great if this can be solved using regex.

Comment: @luxy Added a regex based solution, if it suites you :)

Comment: Thank you limekin and rohit. 
Rohit, I tried your regex it works perfectly well. However, is there a way to print "(isL)(example)(todo)" as a list like one under the other

Comment: @luxy then you've to use the `match` method as in the other answer. With `global` switch of course: `str.match(/\([^()]*\)/g)`

Comment: this regex was exactly the way I wanted to print my strings and the only concern is its printing each parenthesis horizontally. Is there a way to break parenthesis and print line by line with your regex without using match?

Comment: @luxy You can customize the regex to do the replacement with a newline I suppose.

Comment: @luxy Try this out may be: `str.replace(/[^()]+(?=([^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*$)/g, '\\n');`

Comment: it now prints as this "\n(isL)\n(example)\n(todo)\n" and not print in a new line.

Comment: @luxy Oh, make it a single escape - `\n`.

Comment: it prints as same "(isL)(example)(todo)". Is there any regex special character for <br> or something?

Comment: @luxy Where are you printing the result?

Comment: i am printing it in a table row cell. Right now, the cell spans space because it prints it in same line. I would like to break it as a list.

Answer (score 1):

To keep only things inside parenthesis you can use

```
s.replace(/.*?(\([^)]*\)).*?/g, "$1")
```

meaning is:

- `.*?` any sequence of any char (but the shortest possible sequence)
- `\(` an open parenthesis
- `[^)]*` zero or more chars that are NOT a closed parenthesis
- `\)` a close parenthesis
- `.*?` any sequence of any char (but the shortest possible)

the three middle elements are what is kept using grouping `(...)` and `$1`.

To remove everything after the first period the expression is simply:

```
s.replace(/\..*/, "")
```

meaning:

- `\.` the dot character (`.` is special and would otherwise mean "any char")
- `.*` any sequence of any characters (i.e. everything until the end of the string)

replacing it with the empty string

Comment: Thanks for the detailed note. I tried both the examples. For the first example to keep only things inside the parenthesis your regex works and it prints everything inside the parenthesis. But it prints in this format "(isL)(example)(todo)". I want to break each parenthesis and print it in a newline as a list.The second example, to remove everything after the first period, it removes everything after the first period. In this case also I have a list format which looks like this m_name.Luxy, myname.Luxy,etc I want to remove period from each line. Is this also possible from the above regex?

Comment: @rohit's regex "str.replace(/[^()]+(?=([^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*$)/g, ' ');works well when there are parenthesis as this one: (isL)(example)(todo)".Suppose those parenthesis were all dots how do I replace dots with empty space. I would really appreciate some help with this regex, since I am very new to it. Thx